# Trigger in jdbc

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON Recording
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       IF NEW.Format != "WAV" or NEW.Format !="mp3"
            SET NEW.Format = "N/A";
        END IF;
     END//
```

I am getting an error at line 5, I'm trying to run a trigger so that it will not allow any other format to be accepted than mp3 or wav

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NEW.Format = "N/A";
        END IF;
     END' at line 5

Comment: Also you don't need to modify `DELIMITER` because that's only needed in the `mysql` client, to resolve ambiguity about statement termination when SQL is essentially a stream. In most API interfaces (like JDBC), there is no ambiguity because you can only run one statement at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `THEN` keyword in the end of your condition, check the documentation about [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html), and like [Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513435/trigger-in-jdbc#comment81982761_47513525) mention **use single quotes for values as it is SQL ANSI default**

```
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF (LOWER(NEW.Format) != 'wav' OR LOWER(NEW.Format) != 'mp3') THEN 
    BEGIN
      SET NEW.Format = "N/A";
    END; 
  END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: To be clearer, OP missed the "THEN" keyword. Also, use single quotes for values as it is SQL ANSI default.

Comment: this is correct @JorgeCampos i was typing, thank you for the information about *single quotes* :)

Comment: this causes all the formats to go n/a, should it be an 'and' operator instead?

Comment: if i add a new recording and it does not obide mp3 or wav, i want it to show as n/a in the table to show that it doesn't match

Comment: And beware of case, if format is 'wav' or 'Wav' it will be changed into 'N/A'.

Comment: you have to check the exact format like @StephaneM mention there are deffirence between Wav and wav and WAV so to solve this issue you can use `LOWER` for the new format you can check my edit @neymark

Comment: tried using it , but when i add a new field that isn't one of the 2 formats, it changes all of them to n/a?

Comment: Replace the OR by AND as you said earlier.